# Pregunta sobre uso de netflix-zuul

Tags: java, spring-boot

En mi proyecto, tenemos que usar el gateway de netflix-zuul, he estado leyendo sobre esto (ninguno tenemos conocimiento) y en principio parece sencillo de configurar..

En el archivo application.yml, se configura el /path/ por el que vendrá de nuestra aplicación y a que URL llamará, al final es como un puente la libreria de netflix-zuul.

Ahora bien, lo he configurado de la siguiente forma:

zuul:
  debug:
    request: true
  add-proxy-headers: false
  routes:
    autoregistroObtenerBasesLegales:
      path: /pathMiServicio/**
      url: https://www0.app.appcorp.es/widgets/autoregistro/pub/bff/baselegal/getBases?timestamp=1559633204585&language=E&type=TYPE

Y con la misma estructura unos cuanto servicios (son todos idénticos), ahora bien, en principio esto lo que haría es, cuando desde mi app llame a "http://miapp:8080/pathMiServicio/, automáticamente hará la llamada a la URL que está indicada, **¿es esto correcto?**

¿No se debe de configurar  nada más?, viendo por internet he visto que en algunas explicaciones de como usar netflix-zuul, tambien le ponen la anotacion "service-id", pero nose muy bien para que sirve..

Y ahora lanzo mi pregunta, entiendo que esto solo sirve para llamar a la URL específica, ¿no?, es decir, no le podemos pasar parametros a la URL a la que llamamos.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Te recomiendo que añadas la etiqueta `spring-boo` para darle mejor visibilidad a tu pregunta porque el mundo de JAVA es muy grande y mientras mas especifico seas mejores respuestas obtendrás.

Comment: Perfecto, gracias Roberto!!

Answer (score 0):

Si vas a especificar la URL no necesitas el serviceId, el serviceId es cuando utilizas ServiceDiscovery como Eureka o Consul, pero cuando utilizas `path: /pathMiServicio/**` la `url` debes de dejarla desde el punto donde represente el path por ejemplo `https://www0.app.appcorp.es/widgets` de esta forma puedes realizar la llamada `http://miapp:8080/pathMiServicio/autoregistro/pub/bff/baselegal/getBases?timestamp=1559633204585&language=E&type=TYPE` así puedes realizar todas las peticiones posibles a tus servicios ya que la idea de un Gateway es que abstrae la ubicación del servicio y unifica todas las API de los proyectos.

Comment: Entonces Roberto, lo que habría que poner en la URL es hasta el path? por ejemplo:

url: https://www0.app.appcorp.es/widgets/

y despues en el path poner /pathMiServicio/**

Y al hacer la llamada desde mi app, si ponemos :

http://miapp:8080/pathMiServicio/autoregistro/pub/bff/baselegal/getBases?timestamp=1559633204585&language=E&type=TYPE

Lo que estamos haciendo es llamar a la URL indicada (al llamar al path /pathMiservicio/) + todo lo siguiente, (enviada desde nuestra app) y estaría formando toda la URL junto con los parámetros.

Comment: Asi es ya comprendiste como funciona, el path oculta la parte de la url que puede ir cambiando, la decisión hasta que punto ocultara la `URL` del servicio dependerá de los requerimientos, por lo general se oculta desde `www0.app.appcorp.es` que es la parte mas propensa a cambiar.

Comment: Perfecto Roberto, creo que lo he entendido, muchas gracias!

Y otra cosa, a veces los servicios vienen por POST o GET.. entiendo que ahora mismo todo vendría por GET (por parametros), en caso de que venga por el body, ¿como se configuraría en zuul?, porque lo que hemos hablado todo trata por la URL que se le envía. 

Se podría dar el caso de que nos venga algún dato por el body y que sea necesario enviar a través de zuul.

Muchisimas gracias!!

Comment: Javier lee sobre las operaciones REST (GET, POST, DELETE, PUT), los servicios REST al no ser un estándar no es claro en como usar estas operaciones, pero por acuerdo general GET es para obtener información, POST es para una acción que modifica datos y permite agregar un  @RequestBody, PUT una accion que actualiza datos y DELETE accionnes que eliminan datos, si tu servicio acepta estas transacciones depende de tu servicio para zuul es indiferente si es servicio existe se ejecutara y sino se lanzara una excepcion que el servicio no existe.

Comment: Puedes ver este tutorial https://www.nigmacode.com/java/Crear-API-REST-con-Spring y bueno ahora ya solo te queda seguir aprendiendo.